# Как сделать чтобы при в вступление пользователя в супер группу в телеграмм бот отправил ему что он вступил

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Я делал бота и у я попал в тупик. Тупик такой у меня есть бот который дает ссылку на супер группу и мн нужно что бы когда человек был принять бот отправил ему сообщение что его приняли. И еще кое-что нужно что бы бот показывал сколько пользователей в группе когда пользователь выберет.
Вот код:

```
from telebot import types
import telebot

token = ''

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)

    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Графический дизайн")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("3D печать")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("3D дизайн")
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton("Веб технологии")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)

    send_mess = f"<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name}  
✌️</b>\nКакие курсы вас интересують\n<b>1:</b> Графический дизайн\n<b>2:</b> 3D 
печать\n<b>3:</b> 3D дизайн\n<b>4:</b> Веб технологии\nВыберите что вам нужно"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode="html", reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text')
def text(message):

    if message.text == "Графический дизайн":
        messa = "Вот лови ссылку на канал:\nhttps://t.me/+bM5Qas5ic9BmYmQy"

    elif message.text == "3D печать":
        messa = "Вот лови ссылку на канал:\nhttps://t.me/+Lbd0OvCqq3tiZmI6"

    elif message.text == "3D дизайн":
        messa = "Вот лови ссылку на канал:\nhttps://t.me/+6oSnbbEaVhU1YmMy"

    elif message.text == "Веб технологии":
        messa = "Вот лови ссылку на канал:\nhttps://t.me/+WOJRR9oCoGhmZDJi"

    else:
        messa = "Ты что то говориш не понятное"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, messa)



bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простым решением будет это:

```
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def join_request(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
    user_id = update.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(user_id, 'Привет')
    await update.approve()
```

Обратите внимание:

1. При создании приглашения не забудьте поставить галочку на пункте с одобрением администратора.
2. Бот должен быть админом и бот должен иметь разрешение одобрять заявки.

Comment: Извините но мне не нужно что бы бот был админом. Мне нужно было чтобы когда админ разрешает то бот отправляет сообщение или админ не разрешает то бот отправляет сообщение

Comment: Так нельзя - бот не может сам начинать разговор с пользователем. Это запрещено самим телеграмом.