# Как правильно делать рассылку сообщений через telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Как мне отправлять сообщение пользователям, с которыми у меня не было диалога?
Условная конструкция не отправит сообщение, если не было диалога с пользователем.

```
await client.send_message(int(user_id),  'Hello!')
```

```
for user_id in keys_list:
    entity = await client.get_entity(PeerUser(int(user_id)))
    await client.send_message(entity, f'Hello!')
```

Как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Если вы используете bot-API, у меня плохие новости - боты не могут начинать диалог. Единственный, пожалуй, вариант - ставить бота на прием заявок канала, [как тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1457023/462409)

Comment: Удалось решить вопрос? У меня такая же проблема, был бы очень рад, если помогли

Comment: Через эту конструкцию работает, только нужен именно юзернейм, а не ид
`client(SendMessageRequest(username, text))`

Comment: Насколько я нашел информации можно Создать контакт внутри клиента, а потом отправить на него Сообщение. Но реализовать данный метод не получилось у меня, если у кого получится дайте знать !